# I filtered WC Products with custom meta key that have 2000 and 2020 number values, how to filter from 2000 till 2020?

Tags: php, wordpress

I filtered WC Products with custom meta key that have 2000 and 2020 number values like this:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_query_meta_query', 'show_only_products_with_specific_metakey', 10, 2 );
function show_only_products_with_specific_metakey( $meta_query, $query ) {
    // Only on shop pages
    if( ! is_shop() ) return $meta_query;

    $meta_query[] = array(
        'key'     => '_number_field_year',
        'value'   => array('2000','2020'),
        'compare' => 'IN'
    );
    return $meta_query;
}
```

So my question is how to get products that have meta key values from 2000 till 2020?
I mean what should I change here:

```
'value'   => array('2000','2020')
```

Sorry for my poor knowledges.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that `compare` can have `BETWEEN` value:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_query_meta_query', 'show_only_products_with_specific_metakey', 10, 2 );
function show_only_products_with_specific_metakey( $meta_query, $query ) {
    // Only on shop pages
    if( ! is_shop() ) return $meta_query;

    $meta_query[] = array(
        'key'     => '_number_field_year',
        'value'   => array('2000','2020'),
        'compare' => 'BETWEEN'
    );
    return $meta_query;
}
```

That's it!